# Как перезагружать сервер на FreeBSD каждые 30 минут, не используя cron?

Tags: freebsd

Как перезагружать сервер на FreeBSD каждые 30 минут, не используя cron?

Comment: sh скрипт c автозагрузкой....

Comment: руками! каждые 30 минут!

Answer (score 1):

Разрешить использование SW_WATCHDOG (в ядре и в /etc/rc.conf), в а в rc.local написать что-то типа:

```
(sleep 1800 && killall -9 watchdogd) &
```

Answer (score 1):

В linux можно еще и так, вообще не из под root.

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup echo your-root-password | (sleep 1800 && sudo -S shutdown -r now) &
echo "Run shutdown after 30 min"
```